# Getting hierarchy of views of current window in android

Tags: android, performance, layout

Is there any way that I can redraw the views that are showing in current window dynamically. So basically I want to dynamically redraw what is currently showing on screen on a another screen.

For this I want views that are currently displaying and hierarchy of them

I have tried [hierarchyviewer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer). By this I am able to get the view hierarchy for my debug app but not for production apps.

I have also tried AccessibilityService using which I can get AccessibilityNodeInfo tree for all the nodes of current window but I can't get the actual view.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can redraw the views that are showing in current window dynamically

You cannot even *get* the views, unless it is your own content. For example, given any `View` in your `Activity`, you can traverse up the parent chain to the root `View`, then fan out from there. But you cannot get a `View` object from another app.

> I want to dynamically redraw what is currently showing on screen on a another screen

You are welcome to use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+. These do not give you the view hierarchy, but do give you access to screenshots of the current screen content, with user permission.

> I have also tried AccessibilityService using which I can get AccessibilityNodeInfo tree for all the nodes of current window but I can't get the actual view.

That is because the `View` objects are in another process.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. but can you please explain what do you mean by this "That is because the View objects are in another process.". Thanks

Comment: @user3265443: Android apps run in operating system processes, as do apps in most operating systems. And, as with most operating systems, one process does not have access to another process' memory, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Ok.. so you mean AccessibilityService runs as a separate process in android? but how does AccessibilityService know all these things about a view. This is the log I print AccessibilityNodeInfo

AccessibilityNodeInfo@8000927b; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 36, 36); boundsInScreen: Rect(522, 1488 - 558, 1524); packageName: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox; className: android.widget.LinearLayout; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: Home screen 1 of 1, Settings; viewIdResName: null; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; etc

Comment: @user3265443: The Android framework publishes accessibility information to a core OS process, which makes that data available to accessibility services and to assistants (Android 6.0 assist API).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the info

Comment: one more question.. How can hierarchyViewer know the layout, views and its properties... Who push data to hierarchyViewer? Does it takes data from android core process? Do hierarchyViewer also works similar to accessibilityService?

Comment: Is there any possibility you can help me with this question. I want to know how all these things are working

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848598/redraw-the-current-window-views-and-layouts-just-like-ui-automator-tool-of-andr